# React-router-dom how to use the goBack function without usingHistory

Tags: react-router-dom

How can I simulate pressing the "back" button in the browser from the code?

```
const history = useHistory()
history.goBack()
```

I know I can do this as well, but as I understood in the new versions of react-router-dom useHistory was changed to useNavigate, which has no goBack() function. How can I go back to the last page without rolling back react-router-dom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...in the new versions of `react-router-dom` `useHistory` was changed to
> `useNavigate`, which has no `goBack()` function.

This isn't entirely accurate. In `react-router-dom@6` the `useHistory` hook was ***replaced*** by the `useNavigate` hook. The `useNavigate` hook returns a `navigate` function *instead of* a `history` object with navigation methods.

[useNavigate](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate)

> ```
> declare function useNavigate(): NavigateFunction;
>
> interface NavigateFunction {
>   (
>     to: To,
>     options?: { replace?: boolean; state?: any }
>   ): void;
>   (delta: number): void;
> }
> ```

Further

> The navigate function has two signatures:
>
> - Either pass a To value (same type as ) with an optional
>   second { replace, state } arg or
> - Pass the delta you want to go in
>   the history stack. For example, navigate(-1) is equivalent to hitting
>   the back button.

You want to use the `delta` argument. If you recall from RRDv4/5 that `history.goBack()` is equivalent to `history.go(-1)`.

[v4 history](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/v4/docs/Navigation.md)

> ```
> // Go back to the previous history entry. The following
> // two lines are synonymous.
> history.go(-1);
> history.goBack();
> ```

## Solution

> How can I go back to the last page without rolling back
> `react-router-dom`?

In `react-router-dom@6` to issue a back navigation, i.e. POP:

```
const navigate = useNavigate();

navigate(-1);
```